# Добавления содержимое файла в коллекцию

Tags: c#

Осваиваю коллекции. Создал файл txt, в него поместил номера, содержимое этого файла добавил в коллекцию, но есть проблема: содержимое файла добавляется в коллекцию как один элемент. Нужно, чтобы каждая строка файла, добавлялась как новый элемент коллекции. Вот код

```
ArrayList num = new ArrayList();

        // читаем файл
        using (FileStream fstream = File.OpenRead(@"C:\file.txt"))
        {
            // преобразуем строки в байты
            byte[] array = new byte[fstream.Length];

            // считываем данные
            fstream.Read(array, 0, array.Length);

            // декодируем байты в строку
            string textFromFile = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(array);

            //добавляем содержимое файла в коллекцию, тут косяк, номера добавились как один элемент а не отдельный
            num.Add(textFromFile);
        }
```

номера в файле file.txt 12 значные , каждый номер начинается с новой строки.
Думаю, мне следует читать файл по строчно и каждую новую строку заносить в коллекцию в цикле?
Буду рад любым предложениям, тема для меня новая

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Если хочешь просто считать строки:

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(fileName);

foreach (var line in lines)
    // делаем что-то с строкой
```

еще можно через стрим ридер:

```
using (var streamReader = File.OpenText(fileName)) {
  var lines = streamReader.ReadToEnd().Split("\r\n".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
  foreach (var line in lines)
    // Process line
}
```

можно и извратится и читать байтами с буфером:

```
const Int32 BufferSize = 512; // оптимальными значениями для винды и стандартного размера сектора будут 512, 1024 или 4,096 
using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(fileName))
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.UTF8, true, BufferSize)) {
        String line;
        while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
        // делаем что-то с строкой
}
```

---

## Если хочешь что бы числа были числами можно как-то так:

(просто один из множества вариантов)

```
List<double> numbers = new List<double>();

var lines = File.ReadLines(@"C:\file.txt");

foreach (var line in lines)
     numbers.Add( double.parse(line));
```

Comment: Чтение по байтам убрал, сделал чтение построчно через while, все работает отлично) Спасибо за наводку, очень помогло)